# Two controllers one route laravel

Tags: laravel

I can currently show the index page along with a list of posts. The user can select a post to view post details. For this I have:

Routes:

```
Route::get('/', 'PostsController@showPosts');

Route::get('post/{slug}', 'PostsController@showPostDetails');
```

Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Post;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PostsController extends Controller
{

    public function showPosts()
    {
        $posts = Post::simplePaginate(2);
        return view('index', ['posts' => $posts]);
    }

    public function showPostDetails($slug)
    {
        $post = Post::findBySlug($slug);
        return view('post.show',['post'=>$post]);
    }
}
```

Model:

```
public static function findBySlug($slug)
{
    return static::where('slug', $slug)->first();
}
```

index

```
@extends('layouts.index')

@section('header')
<!-- Page Header -->

<header class="masthead" style="background-image: url('img/home-bg.jpg')">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 mx-auto">
                <div class="site-heading">
                    <h1>Train Testing</h1>
                    <span class="subheading">Testing Times</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
@stop
@section('content')
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 mx-auto">

        @foreach ($posts as $post)
        @include('partials.post', ['post' => $post])
        @endforeach


        {{ $posts->links() }}


    </div>
</div>
@stop
```

partials/post.blade.php

```
<div class="post-preview">
    <a href="/post/{{ $post->slug }}">
        <h2 class="post-title">
            {{ $post->title }}
        </h2>
        <h3 class="post-subtitle">
            {{ $post->excerpt }}
        </h3>
    </a>
    <p class="post-meta">Posted by
        <a href="#">{{ $post->author->name }}</a>
        on {{ $post->created_at->format('l d F, Y') }}</p>
</div>
<hr>
```

I now want to show the posts on all other pages. My other pages currently have the route `Route::get('{slug}', 'PagesController@show');` And it makes sense initially to refer back to existing code so use `Route::get('{slug}', 'PostsController@showPosts');` like I did on the home page to display posts there.

However I am not sure of the best way to deal with this as I believe you can not have two controllers for one route.

For other pages I currently have:

Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Page;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PagesController extends Controller
{
    public function show($slug)
    {
        $page = Page::findBySlug($slug);
        return view('page', ['page' => $page]);
    }
}
```

page.blade:

```
@extends('layouts.index')

@section('header')


<!-- Page Header -->
<header class="masthead" style="background-image: url('/storage/{{ $page->image }}')">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 mx-auto">
                <div class="page-heading"> <h1>{!! $page->title !!}</h1>
                    <span class="subheading"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>

@stop

@section('content')

<!-- Main Content -->

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 mx-auto">
            {!! $page->body !!}



        </div>
    </div>
</div>


@stop
```

Answer (score 0):

Pages Controller:

```
use App\Page;
use App\Post;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PagesController extends Controller
{
    public function show($slug)
    {
        $posts = Post::simplePaginate(2);
        $page = Page::findBySlug($slug);
        return view('page', ['page' => $page, 'posts' => $posts]);
    }
```

Then in page.blade.php I can call $posts without any errors:

```
    @foreach ($posts as $post)
    @include('partials.post', ['post' => $post])
    @endforeach


    {{ $posts->links() }}
```

Not sure if this is the neatest way but it works.